# Comparing the RMSE produced by two models

Tags: hypothesis-testing, rms

Suppose I have two models, each of which have the purpose of estimating a sequence of magnitudes. Suppose further that there are $N$ such magnitudes to be estimated, and that each magnitude is know to me, as the creator of the models, such that I can compute RMSE for each model across the $N$ magnitudes.

My question is the following:

When the two models have estimated the $N$ magnitudes, and I have computed the RMSE for each model, what statistic can I then use to determine if the RMSE generated by one model is significantly smaller than the RMSE generated by the other?

Answer (score 1):

The standard asymptotic test is the [diebold-mariano-test](/questions/tagged/diebold-mariano-test); see its [tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/diebold-mariano/info) and literature cited there.

In your particular case, you have [repeated-measures](/questions/tagged/repeated-measures), since each model predicts $N$ different magnitudes. A model accounting for this effect would be appropriate, e.g., a [mixed-model](/questions/tagged/mixed-model).